# How to filter calculated columns in the filtering menu

Tags: 2007, custom-list, filter, calculated-column, dropdown

I would like to display my calculated columns fields in plain text in the filtering drop-down menu when I click on the column title.

I don't know why SharePoint displays my calculated formula instead of my fields, it's not really usefull as filter options for the user.

Have you ever encountered this issue?

I'm using SharePoint 2007 (MOSS), and I don't have permissions to use SharePoint Designer or an other software/solution.

I'm sure I can modify this with JavaScript in a CEWP.

I need help guys... this is making me crazy...

**EDIT:** I uploaded an image, maybe it is easier to understand my needs.

Here is the situation, I clicked on the column title in order to open the filtering menu (top right corner), instead of displaying me "New", "In progress" and "Closed", my 3 Status fields, it shows me my calculated formula that I used to render my fields in color.

[image: Filtering issue]

Comment: I actually wrote my answer in your last one, but it took me 15 mins to write, and you deleted before I could post, so I'll stick it here for now.  Get ready for a novel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I solved it.  And you can't tell me it doesn't work, because I can see it with my own eyes :)  So, that javascript you are running from that guy is unecessary, and it makes things more difficult that they should be.  So you have three columns.  One column has the status, one column determines the color, and the final column has the div tags.  And it's the div tags that are causing the problem.  So, to do it my way, you really only need one column, your status column.  You will actually be using my script to refilter the status column.  You will still have to find the indexes again, but it is much more simple than earlier.  Again, find the ID of your table.  From the table, reference the body that contains all your elements.  I will show you what things in my script stand for.

```
document.getElementById("ID_of_Table").children[2]  //my <tbody> element
document.getElementById("ID_of_Table").children[2].children[4] //one row in my table
document.getElementById("ID_of_Table").children[2].children[4].children[3]  //one field in my table
```

What you want to do, is have the script cycle through all the rows.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function recolorThis() {

  //First, we cycle through the rows
  for(i=1; i<document.getElementById("ID_of_Table").children[2].children.length; i++) {

     //Now we cycle through the each field in one row
     for(j=0; j<document.getElementById("ID_of_Table").children[2].children[i].children.length; j++) {

        //Now we will change text according to what is in that field
        if(document.getElementById("ID_of_Table").children[2].children[i].children[j].innerHTML == "New") {
           document.getElementById("ID_of_Table").children[2].children[i].children[j].innerHTML = document.getElementById("ID_of_Table").children[2].children[i].children[j].innerHTML.replace(/New/, "<div style='font-weight:bold; font-size:24px; color:#00FF00'>New</div>");
          }
        if(document.getElementById("ID_of_Table").children[2].children[i].children[j].innerHTML == "In Progress") {
           document.getElementById("ID_of_Table").children[2].children[i].children[j].innerHTML = document.getElementById("ID_of_Table").children[2].children[i].children[j].innerHTML.replace(/In Progress/, "<div style='font-weight:bold; font-size:24px; color:#FFFF00'>In Progress</div>");
           }

        if(document.getElementById("ID_of_Table").children[2].children[i].children[j].innerHTML = "Closed") {
           document.getElementById("ID_of_Table").children[2].children[i].children[j].innerHTML = document.getElementById("ID_of_Table").children[2].children[i].children[j].innerHTML.replace(/Closed/, "<div style='font-weight:bold; font-size:24px; color:#FF0000'>Closed</div>");
           }

       }  //Closing the j for loop
     }   //Closing the i for loop
  }    //Closing the function

window.onload = recolorThis();
</script>
```

So what my script does, is it takes the entire table of elements in our list, and it cycles through each element row by row, field by field, until it finds a field containing any of your statuses.  When it finds one, depending on what it says, it will replace the text with a  tag, that is styled to how you want.  However, this does nothing to change the actual data in the server, it is still just the simple "New", "In Progress", and "Closed" strings, so that's all that will be displayed in the filter menu.

Of course, you can completely eliminate the second for loop if you know where the text in the fields can be referenced from, increasing performance.  I know the replace function works, I tested it on my site.  I felt like I owed you at least a decent answer before giving up.

Comment: I'm trying it, thank you for your try hardingness Brandon :)

Comment: No problem, felt like I owed you an answer I was satisfied with after throwing so much information at you, haha.

Comment: I made a mistake in the code, will post the updated version.  I tested the whole script on mine, it works :)

Comment: Ahhh.. I changed it myself before you update the code, it was the .children ?

Comment: Oh, awesome!  So does it work for you?

Comment: And yes, the children was changed.  I called the .length of the children[somenumber], which would return 0.  Always call .length after just calling .children, without the brackets.

Comment: Ok it works :)
I was trying it on a "test view" and it wasn't working, but I tried it on my default view and it worked.
But it replaced me all the field, even the "non-status" field by "New". I will work on the script to modify it.
Do it mean that I will have to write a script and add a CEWP in all my views to do specific actions in my views? It is heavy at the performance level no?
Thanks Brandon, you are my hero :)

Comment: I'm very glad I could help! Haha, it helps us both out.  Again, very sorry about leading you down this rabbit hole of answers :)

Comment: I eddited my comment

Comment: You can store this script in a folder you create in your sharepoint hive, and then just load it in any page that uses the site layout.  Something like <script src="pathtoscript">.  Performance wise, it probably isn't the best, but it only runs once when the page is loaded.  I'm sure there are ways to improve performance.  So, likely, it will only be slow to load the page, but performing actions on the page should not have any lag to it.

Comment: It's better to if{} else if{} else if{} else{error msg} for performance instead of 3 if no?

Comment: Actually, it might be better to use the else if.  According to the c++ compiler, it doesn'T matter, but I'm unsure of the javascript compiler.

Comment: Ok, last question (really), the script modify all the fields, but the replace fonction are in the IF conditions, it replace all my fields even in the column date, title etc...
It's like the script is finding "New", "In progress and "Closed in all the rows. The condition are correct, it's weird.

Comment: Can you post your script to the question?

Comment: Also, check to make sure that the if statement has a "==" instead of just the "=".  When I originally wrote the code, I forgot that part, so that might be why it is doing it in all fields.

Comment: I post it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this is a very verbose answer, only because I cannot think of another way around this.  I will try to answer this as easily as I possibly can (no offense to you, I don't mean to make it sound like I am trying to speak down to you, it just involves a lot of steps that involve arguments that will be different for me as they are for you.  To answer your question upfront though, I was able to change the text in the filter menu through one line of javascript, but it took 20 minutes to figure out that one line.

To start, open your site page in chrome or firefox (that's right, it's time to do some tag searching).  And just so you know, none of the HTML elements exist (are null) if the filter menu isn't open, so make sure you have the filter menu open at all times while doing this (on mine it constantly closes after some time, just quickly double click on some text in the source code to stop it from closing if it happens to you).

So the column that has the incorrect filter text should have a unique ID in the tag, I'll call it "ID_of_dumb_column" in this answer.  So now we know how to reference that.  Now, in the HTML, this column has three child elements.  We want the one with the class named something like "ms-core-menu-box".  For me, it was the third  tag that contained it for me.  To do this, follow as such:

```
document.getElementById("ID_of_dumb_column").children[2]  //Indexes start at 0
```

The .children property will return all tags contained within that tag, and stores it into an "array".  When you expand that tag in the debugger, you should see another ul element.  Even though there is only one tag, we need to still reference it like an array. Again:

```
 document.getElementById("ID_of_dumb_column").children[2].children[0]
```

So now we are referencing the ul tag.  Expand the ul tag in the debugger, and you should find li tags.  These lines are now the HTML tags referincing the rows in the filter menu (The "A on top", "Z on top", "" stuff).  Move your mouse over the various li tags to find the ones that correspond to the options you want to change (for me, my first option was at index 4).  To reference this, we write:

```
  document.getElementById("ID_of_dumb_column").children[2].children[0].children[4]
```

I'm going to speed up a little to shorten this already wall of text.  Inside the li tag, there's one a tag at index zero, so do the children thing again for index 0.  Inside the a tag, there are 3 div tags.  I want the one called "labelcompact", it should be the one that covers the text.  For me, that is at index 1, so I call children again at index 1.  Finally, in that div tag there is a span that has the title.  For me, that was at index 0.  Then we set the innerHTML text of that tag.

So **FINALLY** I have this:

```
 document.getElementById("ID_of_dumb_column").children[2].children[0].children[4].children[0].children[1].children[0].innerHTML = "New";  //OR whatever yours is supposed to be
```

Then we want to make sure this line of Jscript is **ONLY** called when the menu is open, so in your script, write:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myfunction() {
document.getElementById("ID_of_dumb_column").children[2].children[0].children[4].children[0].children[1].children[0].innerHTML = "New";
document.getElementById("ID_of_dumb_column").children[2].children[0].children[5].children[0].children[1].children[0].innerHTML = "In Progress";
document.getElementById("ID_of_dumb_column").children[2].children[0].children[4].children[0].children[1].children[0].innerHTML = "Closed";
}

document.getElementById("ID_of_dumb_column").onmousedown = myfunction;
</script>
```

For me, this worked, it changed the text in my filter menu to what I set it as.  The only thing you have to change to change the other options, is move the .children[4] up or down to get all the different li tags for each text you want to change.

Should it work?  Yes.  Is it a good answer?  Heck no, and I'm sure there are better ones out there, but this is all I can think of, and when I tested the .children lines out in firefox debugger, the text changed.  To wrap this up, my layout is different than yours, so your numbers will DEFINITELY be different than mine, and you may have more or less children calls.  Just spend the next half hour or so parsing through the debugger, finding out where the incorrect text lies, and then write a line to travers down, starting from the column ID call.

I really hope this helps! :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myNewFunction() {
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/<DIV font.../g, 'New');  //Fill in the DIV stuff with the whole line that appears in the filter text
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/<DIV font.../g, 'In Progress');
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/<DIV font.../g, 'Closed');
 }

window.onClickFilter = myNewFunction;
</script>
```

Careful though, while this is quick, if you reference the  text, it might cause problems

Comment: I'm testing your answer. If I have to do it for 3 columns in several views (6 or 7), I have to create a CEWP for each view and repete the script for each columns?

Thank you very much, even if it's not the perfect answer, actually it's something to explore.
I will give it a try, if it works with you, I should be able to do it. I'll let you know my feedback if i'm stuck or w/e.

Comment: Actually, think I found a better option, look at the last part of my answer

Comment: There is something I don't understand, when you say my buggy column has "a unique ID". I'm OK with that, but with Chrome (F12), I tried to see if the id change depending with the column. I created 3 calculated columns in my list with the buggy filtering menu. THe ID is always "filter_menu", it's just the numbers of childs which change.
I have the first child "A on top" option, then "Z on top" option, then "Clear Filter from 'myColumnName'" option and finally all my field option with the <DIV etc..
Am I going in a wrong way?

Comment: You can always change the ID value.  All the ID value does is let that item be specifically referenced.  It won't change any properties about the tag itself.  So you can rename it to whatever you want, to make sure it is a unique ID.

Comment: Ok I'm more comfortable now with HTML/JS.
The filtering menu that disappears annoy me so much, when I switch Console/Elements..
Anyways, I can't find the child with the class named "ms-core-menu-box", I even used the search box.

Comment: Did you try my edit at the bottom then?  I believe it should get the job done without having to reference anything of the sort.  And it worked for me.  As far as the ms-core-box thing, it might be different for you.  For me, it was the element that defined the whole filterbox that pops up when you click on the column name

Comment: The .replace() stuff? I tried it, but I'm not sure I did it well. The line is too long, it only display a part of my formula, but it ended with "...", should I let them in the replace fonction?

Comment: I thought that might be just it shorthanding it, and maybe the actual text in the aspx file is the whole thing, so it wouldn't matter...hmm

Comment: Ok I juste have tried both solutions, and it doesn't work.
Either I'm wrong or I'm a real sucker...
I tried parsing all the child elements until the title, but it doesn't change anything. I noticed the "popUpFilterMenu" has a random ID, changing everytime I closed and reopen it. So it's impossible for me to test with a valid ID.

   Finally, I tried your last solution, with the replace function but without success. Here is my test: (copy/paste your script, only changing this line)       [...].replace(/<DIV style='font-weight:bold;font-size:12px; color:Green;'>Closed</DIV>/g, 'Closed');

Answer (score 0):

@BrandonC.

```
var t = document.getElementById("{6638F2B6-64E3-4D26-BE78-24E38C8F3847}-{B7E882E9-A099-47D1-95C9-9E8CAF00E5B7}");


for(i=1; i<t.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].children.length; i++) {
```

It doesn't "enter" in the loop, I wrote something wrong?
My ID is too long, that's why I created a variable.

```
t.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].children.length
```

This displays me "49" in the console, the numbers of rows in my table, I don't understand why I can't enter in the loop, I'm trying to display a "test message" after the For loop without success.

Comment: Why downvote? I don't understand this behaviour

Comment: Sorry, it wasn'T me who downvoted :(  Sorry, I have not seen the notifcation for this answer, so I am just seeing it now.  I am unsure why this is happening, I will try to figure it out myself :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script that I use :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function recolorThis() {

var t = document.getElementById("{6638F2B6-64E3-4D26-BE78-24E38C8F3847}-{B150AAD8-6D16-46ED-98BF-8CFBC3E4BF20}");

//First, we cycle through the rows
for(i=1; i<t.children[0].children.length; i++) {

 //Now we cycle through the each field in one row
 for(j=0; j<t.children[0].children[i].children.length; j++) {  

    //Now we will change text according to what is in that field
    if(t.children[0].children[i].children[j].innerHTML = "New") {
       t.children[0].children[i].children[j].innerHTML = t.children[0].children[i].
       children[j].innerHTML.replace(/New/, "<div style='font-weight:bold; font-size:24px; color:#00FF00'>New</div>");
      }

    else if(t.children[0].children[i].children[j].innerHTML = "In progress") {
       t.children[0].children[i].children[j].innerHTML = t.children[0].children[i].
       children[j].innerHTML.replace(/In progress/, "<div style='font-weight:bold; font-size:24px; color:#FFFF00'>In progress</div>");
      }

    else if(t.children[0].children[i].children[j].innerHTML = "Closed") {
       t.children[0].children[i].children[j].innerHTML = t.children[0].children[i].
       children[j].innerHTML.replace(/Closed/, "<div style='font-weight:bold; font-size:24px; color:#FF0000'>Closed</div>");
      }

    else {
       window.alert("error");
      }


     }  //Closing the j for loop
   }   //Closing the i for loop
 }    //Closing the function

window.onload = recolorThis();
</script>
```

Comment: Change every if(t.children[0].children[i].children[j].innerHTML = "")  To if(t.children[0].children[i].children[j].innerHTML == "").  When I wrote the code, I forgot the two ==.  When you only have one =, the statement is always true, unless there is a typecast error.

Comment: The table of elements ID is different in each views, that means I will add a CEWP with a different script for each views. I think I have no other choice.

Comment: Ahhhh... I'm a noob... it's always "==" or ";" the problem, I should have known it...

Comment: Haha, don't worry, I'm the one that wrote the original mistake anyways.  Yeah, as far as my solution goes, you will have to do it for each view.  If I think of a way, I'll let you know in an update :(

Comment: Ok many thanks Brandon, you were very helpful (Tons of reputation now? xD)

Comment: Haha, plenty enough :)  And your very welcome, I'm glad we could solve this problem!

Comment: @BrandonC. Hi again, I was wondering if it is possible to do the same functionalities/operations in a generic way without using indexes, in order to prevent a modification in the column position, e.g how to make a function to search the table ID, or something else, but here, it's too specific.
Maybe I'm asking too much xD

Comment: Well, since I am using designer, there isn't much I can do when editing the list view page.  If you give each row in the list page a unique ID, you can cut down on searches, and length of code, by just indexing based on the ID.  You could look into CSOM, or more scripting, or editing your list view page .aspx file to give each now row a unique ID or class name.  Just know that class names don't work very well in IE.

Comment: OK I understand. I was asking because, well it's work, but I have 6 different views in my list, so I have to find the table ID for each view (since it's always different), then write 6 different scripts, and working with indexes isn't really reliable. Moreover, when I will template my list to deploy it in other sites, I will have to modify each scripts in all views again, modify the ID etc...
That's why I'm looking for a generic method with the least changes to make when templated.

Comment: What you could do, is find a parent element to the list, and give that an id for each view.  So for me, my table is a child element of a <td> tag with a name that is the same for all views, and it is the fourth child of that parent element.  so instead of the document.getElementById("{numbers}"), you can do document.getElementById("td_tag_id").children[index_of_table]  Just find a parent element that is the same between all views that you can reference.  This is just off te top of my head though, so there might be a better way.  Even though I wrote it, I hate using .children

Comment: Yeah I found a similar solution, my table got an ID, but also a "summary" field which represents the title of my list, it's the same in all my views, and will be the same in all the other sites when the list will be templated. So I will try to loop on each tables and find this summary field. Then, from this, instead of use indexes to find my column, I will use the "ms-viewheader" class with tag header "th" and then find my column.